# Positioning elements using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Just a quick one here. I am trying to position a logo in the top right of my webpage using float:left but it seems to be stuck in the center of the page with the rest of the elements. I have tried to take the text-align:center away from the #showcase but i'm still getting the same results.

```css
#logo h2 {
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url("../img/sky.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header p {
  float: left;
}

#showcase h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-spacing: 5;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>404</h1>
    <p>Oops! the page you're looking for cannot be found</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">GO BACK</a>
    <h2 id="logo">Daily UI</h2>
  </header>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `absolute position` and place the logo exactly where you wish. Also, please note that `#logo h2` is not the correct selector for your logo element. You should use `h2#logo` instead.

Please check the snippet below.

```css
h2#logo {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url("../img/sky.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

#showcase h1 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-spacing: 5;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>404</h1>
    <p>Oops! the page you're looking for cannot be found</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">GO BACK</a>
    <h2 id="logo">Daily UI</h2>
  </header>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is align your items horizontally and have your logo to the right you can wrap all the items in a block element say a `div` and expose flex.

HTML

```
<header id="showcase">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>404</h1>
    <p>Oops! the page you're looking for cannot be found</p>
    <a href="#" class="button">GO BACK</a>
    <h2 id="logo">Daily UI</h2>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `#logo h2` selector won't target anything, as `#logo` has no child `h2` element. You're looking for `h2#logo` or simply just `#logo` (you can only have one element with the ID `logo`, so denoting its tag is pointless).

As for positioning, I'm not exactly sure why you're using flexbox for a parent that also needs an isolated component to the top-right, but I'd recommend making use of **[`position: absolute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning)** with a simple **[`right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right)** offset of around `20px`.

This can be seen in the following (note that the background image was replaced):

```css
#logo {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header p {
  float: left;
}

#showcase h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.2;
  word-spacing: 5;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
  <h1>404</h1>
  <p>Oops! the page you're looking for cannot be found</p>
  <a href="#" class="button">GO BACK</a>
  <h2 id="logo">Daily UI</h2>
</header>
```

Note that `position: absolute` makes `float` irrelevant, so that has been removed.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the response